# While Processing Template in PHPWord It's not opening after saving the template

Tags: php, templates, ms-office, phpword, word-template

I looked for various answers over stackoverflow they all are not working in my case.
my problem is that i am processing a template in PHPWord it is being saved and problem arised now are:
1. document is not opening giving error like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEzjt.png)

2. few blocks are not being deleted or replaced i.e : $templateProcessor->deleteBlock('deleteme'); and $templateProcessor->replaceBlock('replaceme','Hello Dear');  neither giving error nor looking to be executed at last it saves my document. and the document is not being opened.
3. if i comments  $templateProcessor->deleteBlock('deleteme'); and $templateProcessor->replaceBlock('replaceme','Hello Dear'); in my code then everything is fine other things are being executed and also doc is being opened by MS Office Word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem Persist There Was The Complex Value That I was Using In That Block.
I have used replaceBlock() & setComplexValue() over $templateProcessor and its working fine now.